# initialising a structure through pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Suppose we have

```
struct me  {
  int b;
};

void main() { 
  struct me *m1;
  m1->b=3;
}
```

My quesrion is that , as  m1  is a pointer of type  me     and is currently
not holding any address of  variable of type    me    then how we can access    b    which is member of    me
through a pointer which is not pointing to any variable of type    me    and if we can then which variable of type     me     is accesing     a?

Comment: Allocate the memory first- `malloc` ...

Answer (score 3):

It's either

```
struct me m1;
m1.b = 3;
```

or

```
struct me *m1 = malloc(sizeof(struct me));
m1->b = 3;
```

When you deal with pointers in C, you usually need to do 3 things:

- create the pointer
- make sure the memory is allocated where the pointer should point
- make the pointer point to that memory

Your solution only did the first of these.

The reason why your printf works, is that the actual assignment and reading still works. You were overwriting some random memory in your process, this time without any disastrous result. But it's pure "luck". You could have ended up with a segmentation fault as well.

Comment: But my code is 100% working if i   printf m1->b it produces the desired result

Answer (score 1):

1) You *must* allocate space for the object you're pointing to first

2) Then - and only then - can you assign the value m1->b = 3

Answer (score 1):

```
void main()
{
    struct me *m1=malloc(sizeof(struct me)); //here allocating the memory first
    m1->b=3;

    //do what you want to do

    free(m1); //once you allocate the memory, you have to free it after your job is done
}
```

If you do not allocate memory and access (like you have done), you are accessing a part of memory where `m1` points to. It will compile fine. But if `m1` has a value outside the segment of your code, it will give rise to `segmentation fault`. Also if it is within your segment, it may overwrite other values. So it is always desirable to allocate the memory before using it.